# how to 'refresh' ftp on wininet c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ftp, wininet

I'm writing a windows program which is supposed to regularly download a file and then read it into a string, it does it, but only one time at start of the program. Hence if I change the file on ftp meanwhile my program is executing, it will still return the old string. I'm doing stuff with wininet. Here's my function (I just execute it in int main that's all):

```
string downloadstuff() 
    const char * cpath = spath.c_str(); // char path where to download


    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET dFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hInternet == NULL)
    {
        cout << "{Error: " << GetLastError() << "}";
        cout << "1\n";
    }
    else
    {
        dFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "site", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "user", "pass", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
        if (dFtpSession == NULL)
        {
            cout << "{Error: " << GetLastError() << "}";
            cout << "2\n";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!FtpGetFile(dFtpSession, "/cmnds/ctu.txt", cpath, 0, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
            {
                cout << "{Error: " << GetLastError() << "}";
                cout << "3\n";
            }
            else
            {
              cmdf.open("cmnd.txt");
              ssCmd.clear();
              strCmnd.clear();
              ssCmd.str("");
              strCmnd = "";
              ssCmd << cmdf.rdbuf();
              strCmnd = ssCmd.str();
              cmdf.close();
              //remove("cmnd.txt");

              //InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
              //InternetCloseHandle(dFtpSession);
            }
        }
  }

  cout << strCmnd << endl;;
  return strCmnd;
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: To prevent the use of the cached copy pass FtpGetFile INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD.  You still need to close the handles even if FtpGetFile fails.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm a newbie in C++, could you please explain more or give an example (please don't give code without explanation)

Comment: oh i think i get what you're trying to say :D

Comment: Thank you!! You helped me out so much!